Из-за кода, бот не видит другие сообщение, то-есть нету !help, !clear и так далее
Код:
@Client.event
async def on_message(message, member: discord.Member = None):
    channel = Client.get_channel(1238086712924831775)
    if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot:
        channel = Client.get_channel(1238086713855967326)
        guild = (information['guild'])
        await channel.send(f'Logs: ``{message.author.mention}`` кинул заявку в подразделение ``{guild}``')
        await channel.send(f'Поступила новая заявка! Внимание: <@&1238086712404475908>, <@&1238086712404475907>, <@&1238086712404475906>, <@&1244839070933323776>\n * Сообщение будет удалено через 10 секунд.', delete_after=10)

Из-за кода не работают другие команды, help, clear и так далее, покажите слепому человеку что не так

Попробуйте добавить метод process_commands в начало каждого event:
@Client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await Client.process_commands(message)
    channel = Client.get_channel(1238086712924831775)
    if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot:
        channel = Client.get_channel(1238086713855967326)
        guild = (information['guild'])
        await channel.send(f'Logs: ``{message.author.mention}`` кинул заявку в подразделение ``{guild}``')
        await channel.send(f'Поступила новая заявка! Внимание: <@&1238086712404475908>, <@&1238086712404475907>, <@&1238086712404475906>, <@&1244839070933323776>\n * Сообщение будет удалено через 10 секунд.', delete_after=10)


Спасибо, помогло :)

Проблема может быть вызвана неправильным использованием атрибутов декоратора @Client.event.
В вашем коде вы указали member: discord.Member = None как аргумент, но это неправильно для события on_message, которое принимает только один аргумент message.
@Client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = Client.get_channel(1238086712924831775)
    if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot:
        channel = Client.get_channel(1238086713855967326)
        guild = (information['guild'])
        await channel.send(f'Logs: ``{message.author.mention}`` кинул заявку в подразделение ``{guild}``')
        await channel.send(f'Поступила новая заявка! Внимание: <@&1238086712404475908>, <@&1238086712404475907>, <@&1238086712404475906>, <@&1244839070933323776>\n * Сообщение будет удалено через 10 секунд.', delete_after=10)


К сожелению не решит проблему, даже если удалить доп параметр и оставить только message, всё равно так же будет :[
